# xbacklight works, system settings don't affect

Tags: nvidia, backlight, xbacklight

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 x64 on my Dell M4800 with the lvds connected to the Nvidia K2100M via nvidia-355, as the intel card does not support the 3K screen.

So when I change the screen brightness using hotkeys or within energy settings, it doesn't change anything.

When I change it via xbacklight, it works perfect.

So, what's the difference, and is there a way I can help devs to make it work ootb?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's now fixed with the newest nvidia-352  version 352.63.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xbacklight/+bug/1511127

Answer (score 1):

Buggy driver. You can try adding the options `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` to grub

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Add the following parameters to grub configuration:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Update Grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

reboot

Comment: I did this, but it doesn't change...  xbacklight still works, btw.

Comment: Then there really is no solution for your hot keys. You can file a bug report , but it is likely to be against your firmware. You will have to use xbacklight.